# Drupal 7 Views bulk operations based on terms

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I want to do bulk operations based on terms instead of node id. For example, I have a term called "XXXX", I have selected this term for 10 contents. So, in manage views I want to display only the term name, if when user selecting that term and do publish/unpublish, that 10 contents should be publish/unpublish.

Is it possible with Rules? Can anyone please guide me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I use [admin_views](http://www.drupal.org/project/admin_views)
to do that and more.

After enabling it, you'll find Views -> Administration: Nodes, Edit that view.

Under Filter criteria you will find a default "(term) Taxonomy term: Vocabulary (exposed)". 
Add your "(term) Taxonomy term: Name (exposed)" and use the other as referene to get your settings correct.

Pending on how many terms you have, this dropdown can get messy, so you could refine your filter settings to only show some terms in the filter.